# How to find out an element with id partially matched, and change its css style?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a website which execute some javascript while loading, which eventually created a div with id "image_XXXXXXXXX", where the XXXXXXXXX are random numbers.

The question is, how can I grab this div, and change its css style after page loaded? For known id, I can use

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload=function(){
          document.getElementById("image").style.zIndex = '9999999999';
    };
</script>
```

However, since the id contains random numbers, I can't use getElementById() anymore. Any suggestions?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's unusual to have an ID that you can't identify, since that sort of defeats the point, but you can use `querySelector` like so:

```
document.querySelector("[id^='image_']").style.zIndex = 9999999999;
```

Comment: Not often you see querySelector in action!

Comment: @davidkonrad Really? I use it all the time, it's so convenient.

Comment: Yes I agree with @Kolink it defaats the point of the ID.  Instead I think you want to apply a class to all the elements you want to match

Comment: If this is dependent on css support for attribute selectors, there are a few caveats with the method. Mostly IE7, and not especially onerous, but here they are nonetheless: http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/css3attributeselectors#compatibilitysection

Comment: @rusmus I don't think IE7 has `querySelector` anyway, so it doesn't really matter that it doesn't have the CSS selectors either ;)

Answer (score 0):

Another option from `querySelector` is using `match()` based on a `regex` of part of your `id`.

You need to loop through all the matches and set their `zIndex`.

Comment: How would you apply `match()` to html elements? It's a string method, not a DOM method, so to use it for this purpose wouldn't you still need to use DOM methods (e.g., `querySelectorAll()`) to loop through every element on the page and test their ids until you find the one(s) you want?

Comment: I would use jquery `attr()` to extract the `id` and then match them. Since the question was not based on `jquery`, I see how pointless my answer is.